# HowTo convert a MSSQL Dump to MySql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, debian, converters

I'm searching for an way to convert a MS SQL Dump to MySql.

The scenario is that I will get a dump on a daily base and have to import it to my MySql database. There are some restrictions:

1. Since I run a Debian Server I have no option to setup a MS SQL and a MySql in parallel so I can't use taps or an ODBC approach.
2. I will not get direct access to the MSSQL Server
3. the conversion should work on script base, cause I want to use it in a cron task

All solutions I've googled so far require windows or a connection to the MS SQL Server.
Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: define 'ms sql dump'.

Comment: Are you saying you want to dump a DB that you don't have access to...?

Comment: @RemusRusanu: dump means I receive a binary Data export from a customer

Comment: SQL Server has no concept of 'binary data export'. You have to clarify what that file contains. Is a backup? Is an MDF? Is a native bcp export?

Comment: Okay you're right the file itself is readable with some strange encodings as it seems. How can I clarify the export format? Cause the file has no ending like *.bcp or *.mdf. And opening the file is not useful case encoding stuff make it unreadable.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`bcp`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) to create a CSV file from SQL. Use [`LOAD DATA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html) to load it into mysql.

Comment: I don't have access to the origin database. The process is that I receive a dump which I can't influence so far. The Question is there any chance to use this binary data without having MSSQL running.